# Identifying irreps of $SU(2)$

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, group-representations, representation-theory

How does one verify that, the representations of $SU(2)$ corresponding to $j=1/2$ or $j=1$ is irreducible? I think showing the irreducibility (taking the representative matrices into a block-diagonal form is not always trivial.) Is there a theorem which can tell us whether a $SU(2)$-representation is irreducible or not?

Comment: It can be shown that all irreps of $SU(2)$ are equivalent to one of these. I think this is proofed in this book http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-8176-4715-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schur's lemma asserts that a representation is irreducible if its commutant is trivial, that is it only contains multiples of the identity.

Let $G$ be your group and let $\pi$ be any representation of $G$ over the representation vector space $V$ (usually a Hilbert space). Then $\pi$ is a group homomorphism between $G$ and $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$. The commutant of the representation is the set
$$\pi(G)' = \{S\in\text{GL}_n(\mathbb C)\ |\ ST = TS\quad\forall T\in \pi(G)\}$$
i.e. all the elements in $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ that commute with every element in the image of the representation. If $\pi$ is irreducible, by the above mentioned Schur's lemma, this commutant reduces to
$$\pi(G)' = \{\lambda\cdot 1_{\text{GL}_n(\mathbb C)}\ |\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}$$
which means that the only elements that commute with the image of the representation are just multiples of the identity matrix.

The centre of the representation $\pi$ is the intersection $\pi(G)\cap\pi'(G)$, which contains all the elements of the representation $\pi$ that commute with $\pi$ itself. By Schur's lemma, such operators are *scalars*, i.e. just numbers. An example of such an element is the Casimir operator, which in the case of the group $SU(2)$ defines the total angular momentum, and takes the form
$$J^2 = j(j+1)\cdot 1_{\text{GL}_n(\mathbb C)}.$$
Since there is no way of linking two irreducible representations that have a different representation of the Casimir operator (i.e. a different value of $j$) by an intertwiner, every value of $j$ gives you a different (i.e. unitarily inequivalent) irreducible representation.

For the second question, the above argument shows that a test for the irreducibility of a representation is just to check that its commutant is trivial.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative method to Schur's lemma is to use the orthogonality relations of the characters. Let $\chi_R(g)$ be the trace of the matrix of $g$ in the representation $R$. If you have a finite group $G$, with $|G|=n$, there is an inner product between representations
$$\langle \chi_R,\chi_{R'} \rangle = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{g\in G} \chi_R(g)\chi_{R'}(g)^*$$
Now when $R$ and $R'$ are irreducible, this gives unity if $R=R'$ and zero otherwise. This implies that if $R$ is reducible, $\langle \chi_R,\chi_{R} \rangle $ will give some number larger than 1: the sum of the squares of the number of times each irreducible rep appears in $R$.

Of course, $SU(2)$ is not finite, so this is no good. But it works with a simple modification: replace the sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{g\in G}$ with an integral over the group, using the invariant Haar measure, normalised so that the group volume is unity:
$$\langle \chi_R,\chi_{R'} \rangle =\int_{G} \chi_R(g)\chi_{R'}(g)^* dg$$
This works for compact Lie groups $G$. The Haar measure for $SU(2)$ is the usual measure on $S^3$, parametrized be Euler angles, say, and divided by the volume of the sphere to normalize.

So you need to work out the measure on the group, find the traces of the representation, and compute the integral $\int_{G} |\chi_R(g)|^2 dg$. If you get one, then $R$ is irreducible; otherwise, yo will get some integer greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

I will give some more details about @Holographer's answer a little bit, which is completely correct, as I myself struggled with this recently. Some readers might find this proof interesting, as it can not be found very explicitly done in grad math textbooks, only the outline to the proof can be found.

**Theorem:** For continuous class functions $f$ on $SU(2)$, we have:
\begin{equation}
    \int_{SU(2)} fdg=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}\limits f(A(\theta)) sin^2(\theta) d \theta.
\end{equation}
**Proof:**
We know that the Haar measure exists on $SU(2)$. Having that, we want to project it down to the space of conjugacy classes $[0,\pi]$: our goal is expressing integrals of class functions over the group as integrals over $[0,\pi]$. To do so, we want to determine a density $\rho$ on $[0,\pi]$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{SU(2)} fdg= \int_{0}^{\pi}\limits f(A(\theta)) \rho(\theta) d \theta
\end{equation*}
for continuous class functions $f$ on $SU(2)$. The value of $\rho(\theta)$ can geometrically be interpreted as the area of the conjugacy class of $A(\theta)$ in $SU(2)$.

Since continuous class functions can be uniformly approximated by linear combinations of characters of the irreducible representations, according to Fejér's theorem, it suffices to verify that $\rho$ satisfies the formula for all characters $\chi_{n}(A(\theta))$. For these, the left hand side is given:
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{SU(2)} \chi_{n} dg=\langle \chi_n, \chi_0 \rangle_{L^2}=\begin{cases} 
   1 & \text{if } n=0, \\
   0      & \text{if } n>0.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Thus, since $\chi_{0}(A(\theta))=1$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
    1= \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits 1 \rho(\theta) d\theta.
\end{equation*}
Similarly, using our explicit formula for the characters:
\begin{equation*}
    0= \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{i\theta(n-2k)} \rho(\theta) d \theta \iff \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i\theta(n-2k)} \rho(\theta) d\theta=0.
\end{equation*}
Let us check this condition in more detail. For $n=1$ we have:
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i\theta(1-2k)} \rho(\theta) d \theta=0 \iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}) \rho(\theta) d \theta=0. \end{equation*}
For $n=2$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i\theta(2-2k)} \rho(\theta) d\theta=0\iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{2i \theta}+1+e^{-2i \theta})\rho(\theta) d \theta=0 \iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits( e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta})\rho(\theta) d \theta=-1.
\end{equation*}
Similarly, for $n=3$:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{3} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i\theta(3-2k)} \rho(\theta) d\theta=0 \iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{3i\theta}+e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}+e^{-3i\theta})\rho(\theta) d\theta=0 \iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{3i\theta}+e^{-3i \theta}) \rho(\theta) d\theta=0.
\end{equation*}
More generally, for $n \geq 3$:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits   e^{i\theta(n-2k)} \rho(\theta) d \theta=0 \iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{i\theta n}+ e^{-i\theta n}) \rho(\theta) d \theta + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i \theta(n-2k)} \rho(\theta) d \theta=0.
\end{equation*}
Manipulating the second term:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{i\theta n}+ e^{-i\theta n}) \rho(\theta) d \theta + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i \theta(n-2k)} \rho(\theta) d \theta=0 \iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{i\theta n}+ e^{-i\theta n}) \rho(\theta) d \theta + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i \theta((n-2)-2(k-1))} \rho(\theta) d \theta=0.
\end{equation*}
Letting $j=k-1$ and relabeling the second sum:
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits (e^{i\theta n}+ e^{-i\theta n}) \rho(\theta) d \theta + \underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits e^{i \theta((n-2)-2j)} \rho(\theta) d \theta}_{=\langle \chi_{n-2},\chi_{0} \rangle=0 \; \; \forall n \geq 3}=0 \iff  \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits  ( e^{i \theta n}+e^{-i\theta n}) \rho(\theta) d \theta=0.
\end{equation*}
Thus, we obtained:
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits   e^{i\theta(n-2k)} \rho(\theta) d \theta=0 \iff \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits ( e^{i \theta n}+e^{-i\theta n}) \rho(\theta) d \theta=0.
\end{equation*}
The above data can be summarized as:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \rho(\theta) d \theta=1, \; \; \int_{0}^{\pi} ( e^{in \theta}+e^{-in \theta})\rho(\theta) d  \theta= \begin{cases} 
   -1 & \text{if } n=2, \\
   0       & \text{if } n=1  \; \; \text{or}\; \; n \geq 3.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
One can easily see that if $\rho(\theta)=a+b\left(e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i \theta} \right)$, then the conditions for $n=1$ and $n\geq 3$ are immediately satisfied. However, let's show this explicitly. For $n=1$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \left(a+b\left(e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i \theta} \right) \right)\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i \theta} \right) d \theta=2a \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \cos (\theta) d \theta + 4b \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \cos(2\theta) \cos(\theta) d \theta=0.
\end{equation*}
Similarly, for $n \geq 3$:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}  \limits \left(a+b \left( e^{2i\theta} + e^{-2i \theta}\right) \right) \left(e^{i n \theta}+e^{-in \theta} \right) d \theta=2a \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits cos(n \theta) d \theta+ 4b \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \cos(2 \theta) \cos(n\theta)=0.
\end{equation*}
Thus, the only conditions left to satisfy are for $n=0$ and $n=2$. Starting with $n=0$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \left(a+b \left(e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i \theta} \right) \right) d \theta=1 \iff a \pi + 2b \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \cos(2\theta) d\theta =1 \iff  a=\frac{1}{\pi}.\end{equation*}
Finally, for $n=2$ the condition reads:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\limits  \left(a+b \left(e^{2i \theta}+e^{-2i\theta} \right) \right) \left( e^{2i \theta}+e^{-2i\theta}\right)d\theta=-1 \iff 2a \int_{0}^\pi \limits  cos(2\theta) d \theta+ 4b \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \cos^2(2\theta) d \theta=-1.
\end{equation*}
The first term vanishes and we are left with:
\begin{equation*}
4b \frac{\pi}{2}=-1 \iff 2b \pi=-1 \iff b=-\frac{1}{2\pi}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, the measure is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\rho(\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2\pi} \left(e^{2i\theta}+ e^{-2i \theta} \right)=\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{2}{2\pi}(\cos(2\theta))=\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{\pi}=\frac{1-1+2\sin^{2}(\theta)}{\pi}=\frac{2}{\pi} \sin^2{\theta}.
\end{equation*}
As desired, this leads to the correct integration formula:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{SU(2)} fdg=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits f(A(\theta)) \sin^2{\theta)} d \theta.
\end{equation*}
**Corollary:** The representations \begin{equation*}
\pi_n:SU(2) \to GL(V_n), \; \; \left(\pi_n \left(\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ -\bar b & \bar a \end{pmatrix} \right) f\right)(z_1,z_2):=f \left( \left(\begin{pmatrix}\bar a & -b \\ \bar b & a\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2\end{pmatrix}\right)^{T} \right)=f(\bar a z_1 - b z_2, \bar b z_1 + az_2),
\end{equation*}
where  $V_n$ is the space of complex homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in two variables and the characters are given by
$$\chi_{n}(A(\theta))=\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{i \theta(n-2k)}, \; \; \text{where} \; \; A(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta} \end{pmatrix}$$
are irreducible.

**Proof:** $||\chi_n||^2=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \limits \frac{\sin^2(\theta(n+1))}{\sin^2(\theta)} \sin^2(\theta) d \theta=\int_{0}^{\pi} \limits sin^2(\theta(n+1)) d \theta=1,$ where we used
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{i\theta (n-2k)}=e^{i \theta n}+e^{i \theta n-2 i \theta}+ \dots +e^{-i \theta n} =e^{i \theta n} (1 + e^{-2i \theta}+\dots + e^{-2i \theta n} )\\
&=e^{i \theta n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{-2i \theta k}=e^{i \theta n} \frac{1-e^{-2i \theta(n+1)}}{1-e^{-2i \theta}}=e^{i \theta n} \frac{e^{-i \theta(n+1)}(e^{i \theta(n+1)}-e^{-i\theta(n+1)})}{e^{-i \theta}(e^{i \theta}-e^{-i \theta})}\\
&=\underbrace{e^{i\theta n} e^{i\theta} e^{-i\theta(n+1)}}_{=1} \frac{e^{i \theta(n+1)}-e^{-i \theta(n+1)}}{e^{i \theta}-e^{-i \theta}}=\frac{2i \sin(\theta(n+1))}{2i \sin(\theta)}=\frac{\sin(\theta(n+1))}{\sin(\theta)}.
\end{aligned}

**APPENDIX:** Here we show that these are indeed the only irreducible representations. This is solely based on the Dieck, Bröcker book.

**Theorem:** Every irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ is isomorphic to one of the $(V_n,\pi_n)$ introduced above.

**Proof:** Suppose the irreducible representation $W$ with character $\chi$ was different from all the $V_n$. But since $\chi_n$ span a dense subspace, $\chi$ can be approximated by finite linear combinations of $\chi_n$. But this contradicts the orthogonality relations: $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle=1, \langle \chi,\chi_n \rangle=0$.

**References:** Theodor Bröcker, Tammo Dieck, *Representations of compact Lie groups*, Springer, 1995.

*Lecture notes on Representation theory*,Berkeley university.